# takeoff and landing distance GRAPH for a Cessna 150

Tags: performance-calculation

I cannot find a takeoff and landing distance GRAPH for a Cessna 150. The C172 is easy to come by but why no C150?

Answer (score 1):

Cessna publishes its takeoff and landings distances as tables, not as graphs. Example from a Cessna 150M:

[image]

If you find a graph, it's most likely some third-party has made it. If you want one for a 150 and nobody has made one, you'll need to make it yourself or ask somebody else to do it.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Yeah, the third party graph is what I'm looking for. I would have assumed that somebody would have made one of these for the (almost) most popular plane on the planet. I must be asking the wrong question.

Comment: @Greg Do note that different models of 172s have different performance- you shouldn't be using a graph for flight planning purposes unless you've confirmed it matches the one in *your* POH. Personally I find the graphs unwieldy anyway- using a table is much faster.